# .xinitrc not loading .Xresources

Tags: arch-linux, i3, x-resources, xinit

I'm using fresh install of Arch with i3; after logging into I type in `startx` and i3 is starting with default settings, despite the configuration of my .xinitrc:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec i3
exec xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

But when I run `xrdb ~/.Xresources` from the terminal, the colors change to values configured in .Xresources

Comment: As the wiki makes abuntantly clear, [the lines following an exec command will be ignored](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.xinitrc` you need to execute `xrdb` first and then launch `i3`. E.g:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
exec i3
```

Comment: startx wont' work with such configuration (i3 is not launching)

Comment: Is it working with new example from my answer?

Comment: It should be `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`